# Failed dynamic config update

Tags: swift, snapkit

I'm trying to "send" an image to snapchat using the Snapchat Creative Kit SDK.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import UIKit
import SCSDKCreativeKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func addToSnapBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {


        let urltest = URL(string: "http://via.placeholder.com/750x1334");

        if let urltest = urltest as? URL {
            let picture = SCSDKSnapPhoto(imageUrl: urltest.absoluteURL);
            let snapPicture = SCSDKPhotoSnapContent(snapPhoto: picture);

            snapPicture.caption = "Test image";
            snapPicture.attachmentUrl = "https://google.com/";

            let api = SCSDKSnapAPI();
            api.startSending(snapPicture) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error);
                } else {
                    print("YES");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

When the user clicks on the button that is linked to the "addToSnapBtn" method I get the following error:

```
2019-06-14 00:38:14.454846+0200 prosnap[1540:84256] [SnapKit] path=/v1/config trace_id=917679DA29A144CEB5AD8E4C9446FB45
2019-06-14 00:38:14.808965+0200 prosnap[1540:84256] [SnapKit] Dynamic config update status: failure
```

I've looked everywhere. Documentation, google, stackoverflow, you name it.

I'm relatively new to iOS app development and I have no experience with snapkit.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it fail at `api.startSending(snapPicture)` ? Try to put some `print("TOKEN")` in your code to see where it exactly fails, or use the debugger if you are comfortable enough with it. ( and btw, you dont need the `;` in swift )

Comment: Figured it out, had to include my Bundle ID in the app settings (At snapkit)

Comment: Hi I'm getting same just instead of "Dynamic config update status: failure" I'm getting  success but it's not redirecting to Snapchat, Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Don't define `let api = SCSDKSnapAPI()` in function. Define it in `UIViewController`. Because when you define `let api` in function it will deinits before completion runs. I tried and it works.